# WebApi Odata, restrict few columns based on user role

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have multiple roles that can access my odata service and based on the role, I need to hide few columns. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Where is your code! what have u tried so far?

Comment: So, these are the things I have tried: 1. Explored Queryinterceptors, but they are a feature of wcf and not webapi. Correct me if I am wrong. I couldn't find examples related to webapi. 2. I tried tograbbing the role in my controller and write a linq select statement to project the base object. Something like: .Mydata.Select(p=>new myobject {myobject.Property1=p.property1,....};  based on role. But this gives my an error because I am trying to project an existing object.

Comment: Have you tried to add a `.ToList().Select(...)` to it? You often need to change from sql to entities to objects to entities to make projection work.

Comment: The problem with ToList() is that it materializes the query and that takes a hit on the performance. I type of data I am querying has millions of records, although I have defined the page size.

Comment: Maybe you can do this using a validator?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/02/06/protect-your-queryable-api-with-validation-feature-in-asp-net-web-api-odata.aspx. You might be able to "validate the $select, $expand & $filter" based on your security rules. Not sure of the complexity level of it :S

Answer (score 0):

1. Customize DefaultODataSerializerProvider.

   ```
   public override ODataSerializer GetODataPayloadSerializer(IEdmModel model, Type type, HttpRequestMessage request)
   ```

   Override GetODataPayloadSerializer method, get the role through request, store it in your cusomer serializer, return your customer serializer.
2. If you return a entity, Customize ODataEntityTypeSerializer

   ```
   public override ODataEntry CreateEntry(SelectExpandNode selectExpandNode, EntityInstanceContext entityInstanceContext)
   ```

Override CreateEntry Method, remove properties through the role. like:

```
            var idProp = selectExpandNode.SelectedStructuralProperties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Id");
            if (idProp != null)
            {
                selectExpandNode.SelectedStructuralProperties.Remove(idProp);
            }
            ODataEntry entry = base.CreateEntry(selectExpandNode, entityInstanceContext);
            return entry;
```